# Кастомный app.config

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Подскажите, как сделать кастомную секцию, которая бы была коллекцией, а каждый элемент коллекции имел несколько атрибутов?

Т.е я допустим хочу, что бы я моu работать таким образом с конфигурацией:

```
Settings.Default.CustomConf[0].attr1
Settings.Default.CustomConf[0].attr2
```

Comment: А нафига париться с конфигами? )) Юзаешь любой сериалайзер, чтение и запись на пару строк, объекты и колекции любые

Comment: Я согласен, что можно хранить конфигурацию в отдельном XML, а потом, как хочешь так и работай с ним. Но зачем плодить лишние файлы, когда можно юзать app.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class StartupFoldersConfigSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty( "Folders" )]
    public FoldersCollection FolderItems
   {
        get { return ( (FoldersCollection)( base[ "Folders" ] ) ); }
    }
}

[ConfigurationCollection( typeof( FolderElement ) )]
public class FoldersCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new FolderElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey( ConfigurationElement element )
    {
        return ( (FolderElement)( element ) ).FolderType;
    }

    public FolderElement this[int idx ]
    {
        get{return (FolderElement) BaseGet(idx); }
    }
}

public class FolderElement : ConfigurationElement
{

    [ConfigurationProperty("folderType", DefaultValue="", IsKey=true, IsRequired=true)]
    public string FolderType
    {
        get {return ((string) (base["folderType"]));}
        set{base["folderType"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty( "path", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = false, IsRequired = false )]
    public string Path
    {
        get{return ( (string)( base[ "path" ] ) ); }
        set{base[ "path" ] = value; }
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
StartupFoldersConfigSection section = (StartupFoldersConfigSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection( "StartupFolders" );

if ( section != null )
{
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( section.FolderItems[ 0 ].FolderType );
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( section.FolderItems[ 0 ].Path );
}
```

Конфиг:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="StartupFolders" type="ConfigSectionTester.StartupFoldersConfigSection, ConfigSectionTester"/>
</configSections>

<StartupFolders>
    <Folders>
        <add folderType="A" path="c:\foo" />
        <add folderType="B" path="C:\foo1" />
    </Folders>
</StartupFolders>
```

Comment: А можешь еще сам app.config выложить?

Comment: добавил конфиг в пост